# How to convert detected url in text to link in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am making a SNS website and trying to convert detected url in text to shown as links.

```
import React from "react";
import "./PostCard.css";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import datePretty from "../../helperFunctions/datePretty";

function PostCard({ userName, postTime, likeCount, commentCount, postText }) {

  var pastTime = datePretty(postTime)

  return (
    <div className="postingCard">
      <div className="postingHeader">
        <div className="postingProfile">
          <img className="postPP" src="profile.png" alt="Sample profile"></img>
        </div>
        <div className="postingWriter">
          <h3>{userName}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="dateWritten">
          <h4>Posted {pastTime} ago</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="postSetting">
          <i className="fa-solid fa-ellipsis fa-2xl" id="postSet"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="postingBody">
        <div className="postingSection">
          <div className="postWords">
            <h4>{postText}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="iconSection">
          <div className="likeSection">
            <i className="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up fa-2xl" id="like"></i>
            <div className="likeCount" id="likeNum">
              {likeCount}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="commentSection">
            <i className="fa-regular fa-comment-dots fa-2xl"></i>
            <h5 className="commentCount">{commentCount}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PostCard;
```

This is my code that I currently working on. The **postText** is the element that I tried to convert to shown as link.

For example, when I uploaded like "hello, https://www.youtube.com", then https://www.youtube.com should be able to click and redirect to YouTube.

Can you please tell me how to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the logic to detect a url in the original string is already built and that what you are passing down in postText is a string containing a url, you can wrap an anchor tag around your h4 and simply set the href property to {PostText}

```
<a href={postText}>
  <h4>{postText}</h4>
</a>
```

If you intend to have it open in a new tab make sure to set target to _blank and rel to noreferrer

```
<a href={postText} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
  <h4>{postText}</h4>
</a>
```

Comment: If there was a postText calling "hello, https://www.youtube.com", it interprets hello as a link as well. Is there any different detections that hello is not interpreted as a link?

Comment: I believe that the logic within the useEffect in qublaidev's answer is a good approach to detecting the url itself and storing that as a separate piece of state within a component. Pass down your postText as a prop, make a copy of it's contents, and then edit that copy to only contain the url using string/array methods. Set the src to be based off of this copy.

Answer (score 1):

The react way of doing this would be to create a react component and pass the text as props, and handle the logic inside that component.

Here is my take on this, you should change the link detection to your needs.

```
   export default function PostText(props) {
  
   const [isLink,setIsLink] = useState(props.text.includes("http"))
   const [textArr,setTextArr] = useState([])

   useEffect(()=> {
     const txt = props.text
     if (txt.includes("http")) {
       setIsLink(true)
        const firstIndex = txt.indexOf("http"); //find link start 
        const linkEnd = txt.indexOf(" ",firstIndex) //find the end of link
        const firstTextSection = txt.slice(0,firstIndex)
        const linkSection = txt.slice(firstIndex,linkEnd)
        const secondSection = txt.slice(linkEnd)
        setTextArr([firstTextSection,linkSection,secondSection])
     } else {
       setIsLink(false)
     }
   },[])
  return isLink ? (
    <div >
      <p>{textArr[0]}</p>
      <a href={textArr[1]} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Link</a>
      <p>{textArr[2]}</p>
    </div>
  ) : (
  <div>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
  </div>)
}
```